# How to sanitize an xml file with jquery, ie replace illegal chars with html entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html-entities

I have a jquery get command which gets the contents of an xml file.  Unfortunately, some of the xml files i'm reading have unescaped special characters in them ('&' for example).

Initially i was using the `datatype: "xml"` option with the $.get, and this was blowing up because the unescaped chars make the xml illegal.  So, i thought i'd use `datatype: "text"` instead, and then, in my `success` block, sanitize the text before turning it into a proper xml object with `$.parseXML`.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?  Eg of taking some text like eg

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> <data> <title>Games & Vocal Warm-Ups</data>
```

and turning it to

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> <data> <title>Games &amp; Vocal Warm-Ups</data>
```

Or, is there an alternate way to parse the xml which will forgive or automatically handle the unescaped entities?

thanks, Max

Comment: No chance to inform the source about the bug and having the bug fixed?

Comment: +1 in the long run the only answer is to correct the service that delivers non-well-formed material - it is technically not XML and all other parsers will refuse to touch it too. Brushing the problem under the carpet by 'fixing' `&` and `<` characters that don't look right only works up until content has data that looks 'right enough' and then you still blow up.

Comment: yes, i could fix it by amending the xml files on our filesystem.  But there are a lot of them, and i was wondering if i could deal with it at the client end in the meantime.  I agree that fixing them at source would be ideal but it's not, strictly speaking, what i asked.

Comment: I did actually end up fixing 9000ish problematic xml files at the source, which was about 3 days work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about a quick way to solve it using JavaScript but there is a nice tool called [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/) which can solve it:

[Fix Invalid Characters in XML](http://www.powergrep.com/manual/xmpxmlfixentities.html)

From the manual:

> Sometimes, XML files generated by poorly written software or by
>   careless programmers will contain lone characters like < and &. These
>   will cause the XML file to be rejected by XML parsers. They must be
>   replaced with the entities < and &. Using PowerGREP, we can
>   easily fix this with a search-and-replace using two regular
>   expressions.

So you can run it on your XML files in the server before using them in your JS code.

**Update:**

Now look, it is all about regular-expressions, so you can surely use JavaScript's `replace` function to achieve it, just track the manual link here and project it on your JavaScript code.

Here is an example of replacing any `<` symbol that is not followed by what looks like a valid XML tag:

```
yourXmlString.replace( new RegExp("<(?![_:a-z][-._:a-z0-9]*\b[^<>]*>)") ,"gm"), "&lt;");
```

Comment: Thanks for the PowerGrep link.  For a coder like myself, rolling my own solution (like you started doing) is always tempting but i'd rather use a library.

Comment: No, i was hoping that one would appear in an answer to this question :)

Comment: You can wait or write your own library to handle it - see my code and the additional regular-expressions at the link I provided.